# How to launch an Android app without "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"

Tags: android

I want to know how to launch an `Android app` without:

> android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If removing line 3, the app will not be in the launcher. The question is: where and how can I launch this app in other way?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Can you please answer my que   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383167/android-hide-application-from-the-list-of-applications-and-assign-a-short-key-fo   . Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use a `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class SafetyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ActivityManager as = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (IsNavigationRunning(as)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, VoiceActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/fot"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.Safety.VoiceActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CompletelyTransparentWindow" >
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.Safety.SafetyReceiver"
        android:process=":goodprocess" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

This is an example that starts when a text is received.

Comment: Great! Using a SMS to trigger the activity, very imaginative. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan .. where is <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> line in above androidmenifest code?

Answer (score 2):

This would be better if you want to launch a custom activity, for example on a button press:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xBtn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer");
                    intent.setComponent(ComponentName
                        .unflattenFromString("it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer/it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer.MainActivity"));
                    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                    startActivity(intent);
             }
});
```

And this is the manifest associated with your custom activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where

```
Intent intent = new Intent("it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer");
```

corresponds to the line

```
<action android:name="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer" />
```

And

```
intent.setComponent(ComponentName
                        .unflattenFromString("it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer/it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer.MainActivity"))
```

corresponds to the 2 lines

```
package="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer"  the part before /
android:name="it.prassel.vimsmediaplayer.MainActivity" the part after /
```

Your custom activity will not appear neither in the Menu nor in the Recent Apps, it will be completely anonymous. Pay attention, if you wish to be the only one who can acced to your app, to give the intent-filter a meaningful name

Comment: I am getting "ActivityNotFound" exception when i try to launch it from another app. Could you tell me what more needs to be added, to open the app without launcher.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to launch an Android app without: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

In Android, an Activity should be started by an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Intents can start an Activity with startActivity(Intent myIntent), example:

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(context, target_class.class);
                    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You must replace "myIntent", "context" (usually a "this") and the "target_class" with your variables, in order for this to work.
So, whenever you need your activity, call the Intent, ans the OS will resolve for the Activity

Answer (score -1):

you can specify in your class.
For example on clicking of a button you want to go to some activity. so just write this code:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xBtn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intnt = new Intent();
          intnt.setAction(android.intent.action.MAIN);
          intnt.setCategory(android.intent.category.LAUNCHER);
          startActivity(intnt);
         }
        });
```

Comment: In fact, I tried .removeCategory(android.intent.category.LAUNCHER); to see if it can remove the app icon from the launcher but it failed.