# How to hide android app from launcher

Tags: android

I would like to hide my android app from the launcher, but be able to call it from within another app. I am lost on what to remove from the android manifest.

Already tried removing...

`<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`

...but then it doesn't open when called from another app.

Here is what how I am calling this hidden

```
        Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {
                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.xbmc.xbmc");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);

            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
```

Here is the top of the manifest

```
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:hasCode="true" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name=".Splash" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to remove the following line from your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

This will remove the application from the default launcher. However, you also need to add the following line such that your `BroadcastReceiver` is not completely ignored:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

You should NOT remove the line below - it is used to specify which `Activity` should launch first when your app is opened:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

**EDIT**

In order to launch the application discussed above from another application, you cannot use the calls shown in your question. You are trying to open the application by creating an `Intent` with the `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` tag (`i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)`) when you have explicitly removed the following line from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

The absence of the above line means that the application you are trying to call will ignore the launch `Intent`. In order to launch your application you will need to act upon another `Intent`. Here is an example that shows how to open an application, which doesn't contain a launch intent filter, by responding to a SMS `Intent`: [How to launch an Android app without "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414272/how-to-launch-an-android-app-without-android-intent-category-launcher)

Which intent you choose to use is up to you - just make sure you add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: can you post your entire `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Also, how are you opening this application from your other application?

Comment: added to my original post ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
   p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134884/android-how-to-programmatically-hide-launcher-icon).

hope this helps.

Comment: Add it in the onCreate of the MainActivity