# how to hide my launcher app from application stack?

Tags: android, launcher

I am creating a launcher app but whenever i click on open application button it's also showing my launcher app. how can i hide my launcher from the application stack.

i found some launcher's that are hidden from stack like [Microsoft Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher)

[Microsoft Launcher output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czvs1.gif)

**ManifestFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

   <!-- <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo_bg"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.AppListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.PinActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>-->

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.SettingActivity"
            android:label="Settings" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

how can I hide my launcher app like this app.
please suggest me, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: show your manifest

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide android app from launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990832/how-to-hide-android-app-from-launcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to your Activity (all Activities?) in manifest. This will remove the activity from recent/running apps menu

Comment: it's working but if i open other application(ex. clock) and press back it redirect me to mobile launcher when my launcher is already default launcher

Comment: @ChiragPatel that's another question. If you have another question - ask another question

Comment: It won't be good for stackoverflow if I answer some other question in this question, so please open another question.

Comment: check my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628370/while-opening-other-app-from-launcher-it-app-close

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, "your class name"); 
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

above code write in launcher Activity