# How to modify an apk to hide from launcher?

Tags: java, android

I want to modify an apk as hidden application. please give possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the following line from your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

This will remove the application from the default launcher. However, you also need to add the following line such that your `BroadcastReceiver` is not completely ignored:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

You should NOT remove the line below - it is used to specify which `Activity` should launch first when your app is opened:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

In order to launch the application discussed above from another application, you cannot use the calls shown in your question. You are trying to open the application by creating an `Intent` with the `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` tag (`i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)`) when you have explicitly removed the following line from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

The absence of the above line means that the application you are trying to call will ignore the launch `Intent`. In order to launch your application you will need to act upon another `Intent`. Here is an example that shows how to open an application, which doesn't contain a launch intent filter, by responding to a SMS `Intent`: [How to launch an Android app without "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414272/how-to-launch-an-android-app-without-android-intent-category-launcher)

Which intent you choose to use is up to you - just make sure you add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide the icon:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Use this to bring it back:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

All the best! :)